# Pressure increment in the gap between two parallel plate capacitors

Tags: pressure, capacitance, dielectric

What is the pressure increment in the gap between two parallel plate capacitors when they are immersed in water horizontally with a constant voltage of 500? Take dielectric constant = 81, distance between plates = 1mm.